# Google Maps Embed API Rejection

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

I'm getting a

`The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.`

error on my sites, even when I set my browser referrers to be `*.*`

---

I have these set:

[image: My APIs I have turned on]

---

[image: The key screen]

---

The code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Hamilton%20Christian%20Reformed%20Church%2049419&key=***************************x5w1gMU9tAoRPg"></iframe>
```

---

All of this was generated by [Google's Map Embed tool](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start). I've tried changing the allowed referrers to `*.mydomain.com/*` with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use the referer `*.*/*` or don't use any referer.

`*.*` will match `domain.com` but not `domain.com/filename.ext`

Comment: Still no luck. I get the same error. I have also tried using the actual domain ( `*.mydomain.com/*` ) with no luck.

Comment: I have removed all referrers and I still get `The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.`.

Comment: maybe a caching-issue, try another browser(note: when you refresh a browser-window  included iframes often will not be refreshed)

Comment: The SAVE button on https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxxxxx/apiui/credential/key/0 was causing trouble for me. I have to press the button a few times and reload and repeat until the entry actually showed up in the list

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as Full Decent, in that the save button wasn't actually saving. Clicking it a few times sorted it - you should see an animation state on the button (as below) and then get redirected to the API credentials index page when it works.

[image: Save Google API Credentials]

Answer (score -2):

Check out the request your browser is sending out, in my case the referer was set to www.google.com.